# R - nflscrapr season_by_season error

Tags: r

I am having issues getting the `season_by_season` function of `nflscrapr` to work

**Must install the devtools package using the below code**

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
# For now you must install nflscrapR from github
if (!is.element("nflscrapR", installed.packages())) {
  # Print Installing nflscrapR
  devtools::install_github(repo = "maksimhorowitz/nflscrapR")
}
```

**Load the package**

```
library(nflscrapR)
```

**documentation about play by play data**

```
help(game_play_by_play)
```

**attempt to get season 2013 data, error occurs**

```
pbp2013 <- season_play_by_play(2013)
```

**Error:**

> pbp2013 <- season_play_by_play(2013)
>   Error in `[<-.POSIXlt`(`*tmp*`, not_same, value = c(1474949700, 1474949700,  : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: `GameID 
(character or numeric) A 10 digit game ID associated with a given NFL game.` Seems like you cannot use dates.

Comment: Have you contacted the author? At least post the relevant code for the function that doesn't work.